# why and where rails escaping my html tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping

I have some code:

```
def send_custom_mail
  p params[:text]
end
```

I'm sending some tags like < b >, but in console i can see this :

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qweqweqwe", "to"=>"qweqwe@qweqwe.ru", "subject"=>"qweqwe", "text"=>"qweqwe<b>asde</b>", "commit"=>"Save changes"}
....some sql....
"qweqweasde"
```

So tags came to my code, but i cant get it =(
What should i do to get my tags back ?

I've tried "p params[:text].html_safe", its not helping me!

**UPDATE**

I have found the solution - it was code from previous programmer:

```
def filter_params_tag
  params.each_pair do |k,v|
    begin
      params[k] = strip_tags(v)
    rescue
      next
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where/how are you using this send_custom_mail method?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `CGI::escapeHTML`

```
def send_custom_mail
  p  CGI::escapeHTML(params[:text])
end
```

Thanks

Comment: still converting "text"=>"qwe<br>\r\nqweqwe<b>asd</b>"
to "qwe\r\nqweqweasd"